# How does django take queryset without database hitting?

Tags: python, django

There are so many answers and articles to say queryset in django is lazy, it isn't evaluated until you actually do something with queryset.

My question is how is it possible? How does the methods, filter(), all() or order_by() etc, work not knowing what data the objects have?

I assume that hitting a database and knowing data in model objects is different. But, it doesn't make sense for me.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

queryset aggragate all filters, excludes annotates and somethins like that and when you do something with this queryset, django generate query (from filters etc. do sql query) to database and after that do qyery do database